# Why is Stack Overflow skipping & and ! sign in question titles?

Tags: support, seo, special-characters

I found my post title with special characters like & and ! being skipped and generated without them. I would like to know why is it done?

I found similar problem while forwarding user request with & and ! sign to another page via .htaccess.

like it:
user req pages/feedback & conact.htm and needs to be redirected to index.php?page=feedback & contact

Is it for the same reason do we have to skip those symbols or is there any other reason?

Comment: Better raising this question at meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Questions about stackoverflow.com belongs in meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: With slightly different wording this question might not have been migrated and might have had some decent answers.  For instance, if it referred to "some sites" exhibiting this behaviour and included SO as one of them, would it have been migrated?

Comment: Yup, I agree this shouldn't have been migrated. It is not really a Meta question.

Comment: @Pekka: I think it's unclear if the OP is asking about SO or about one of his/her projects. May as well leave it here for one of the devs to answer.

Comment: If we're going to complain about a stripped character go with `+`. A question with the title "C++ problem" turns into `stackoverflow.com/.../c-problem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> found my post title with special characters like & and ! being skipped and generated without them. I would like to know why is it done?

The `&` is a reserved character and illegal to use in an URL, as are e.g. `?`, `:`, and `,`. Most "URL generating" functions strip out any and all special characters to avoid problems.

The alternative would be to URL-encode these characters with %nn sequences.

Comment: Exactly and that's why this question was about web programming and not SO itself. I think it should not have been moved.

Comment: It can be somewhat fine than others

Comment: @allesklar, the __answer__ is about web programming.  The OP might have had no idea that the answer had to do with programming, but there's no doubt that the question is about SO.  Migration seems justified in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This request is so completely nonsensical it feels like an enormous waste of my time.

why in the world would we want..

#### Why is Stack Overflow skipping & and ! sign in question titles?

to be...

`/questions/57577/why-is-stack-overflow-skipping-ampersand-and-exclamation point-sign-in-question-titles`

Or, even worse

#### I got a question!

to be...

`/questions/12345/i-got-a-question-exclamation-point`

Answer (score 1):

Your question has & and ! in the title and they both are working fine.

Comment: Check the URL generated from the question title "why-is-stack-overflow-skipping-and-sign-in-question-titles" (to quote just the title).

Comment: The OP didn't say that they cared about that.

Comment: yeah i am surely pointing about the url being generated

Comment: Why do you care about that?

Comment: want to know why can't we use it in url. is it due to htaccess problem